# I think I am not understanding pointers fully, but why is there a difference in the outputs here?

Tags: c++, pointers

Below I have a snippet of my code. Basically, I am wondering why there is a difference in output when I individually print `contextFile[0]` and `contextFile[1]` versus through a `for` loop.

In `contextfile.txt` (which is the value of `target_file_name` in this case), I have the following:

> hickory dickory dot had a little farm you feel me.

Here is the code:

```
cin >> target_file_name;
ifstream fileExist(target_file_name);
if (fileExist)
{
    int count = 0;
    int contextSize = 1000;
    int keySize = 1000;
    char *contextFile;
    char *keyFile;
    contextFile = new char[contextSize];
    keyFile = new char[keySize];
    string command;
    fileExist >> contextFile[count];
    while (!fileExist.fail())
    {
        count++;
        fileExist >> contextFile[count];
    }
    cout << "printing individual: " << contextFile[0] << contextFile[1];
    cout << "Printing the contextfile array: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cout << contextFile[count];
    }
```

When I print individually, I get `hi`, which is the correct output.

When I print through the `for` loop, I just get straight `================`.

Why is there a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Because you print

```
cout << contextFile[count];
```

over and over again, instead of

```
cout << contextFile[i];
```

in your loop, resulting in undefined behavior, since `contextFile[count]` was never initialized.

Comment: Just checked the code again and my understanding - there is an attempt to read the final `contextFile[count]`, but on EOF it will - well, [my reference doesn't say](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) - probably be unset, but at least not a useful value, so my (now deleted) comment is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are printing only one value inside the `for` loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    cout << contextFile[count];
}
```

You need to make changes in that

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    cout << contextFile[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input file has 50 characters in it.  So, after your reading loop is finished, `count` is 50, and `contextFile[0]` up to and including `contextFile[49]` have been populated with data.

You are then outputting the first two individual characters of `contextFile[]`, which is fine.

Then you are running a loop through the first `count` characters of `contextFile[]`, which is also fine.  But on every loop iteration, you are outputting `contextFile[50]`, which has not been populated with any valid data.  You should be outputting `contextFile[i]` instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    //cout << contextFile[count];
    std::cout << contextFile[i];
}
```

That being said, I would suggest NOT using a `char[]` at all:

```
std::getline(std::cin, target_file_name);
std::ifstream theFile(target_file_name);
if (theFile)
{
    std::vector<char> contextFile;
    char ch;

    theFile.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end); 
    size_t size = theFile.tellg();
    theFile.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg); 

    contextFile.reserve(size);
    while (theFile >> ch)
    {
        contextFile.push_back(ch);
    }
    /* alternatively:
    contextFile.reserve(size);
    std::copy(
        std::istream_iterator<char>(theFile),
        std::istream_iterator<char>(),
        std::back_inserter(contextFile)
    );
    */
    /* alternatively:
    contextFile.resize(size);
    theFile.read(&contextFile[0], size);
    size = theFile.gcount();
    contextFile.resize(size);
    */

    std::cout << "printing individual: " << contextFile[0] << contextFile[1]" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Printing the contextfile array: " << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < contextFile.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << contextFile[i];
    }
    /* alternatively:
    for (std::vector<char>::iterator iter = contextFile.begin(); iter != contextFile.end(); ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << *iter;
    }
    */
    /* alternatively:
    std::copy(
        contextFile.begin(),
        contextFile.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout)
    );
    */
    /* alternatively:
    std::cout.write(&contextFile[0], contextFile.size());
    */
```